# Boot volume full?, problem removing old kernels

Tags: boot, apt, kernel

I know there are a lot of questions on this but I have been through a lot of them and can't seem to get past a problem.

Steps so far -

- Removing old kernels via apt -> Fails due to lack of space

So moving on I tried to backup the old kernels and remove them from /boot in order to create space to run apt-get -f install but this still fails with the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-63
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-63
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 64 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 8,874 kB of archives.
After this operation, 63.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirror.eu.oneandone.net/ubuntu/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-headers-3.13.0-63 all 3.13.0-63.103 [8,874 kB]
Fetched 8,874 kB in 0s (9,998 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 330796 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.13.0-63_3.13.0-63.103_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.13.0-63 (3.13.0-63.103) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-63_3.13.0-63.103_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-63/net/unix/Makefile.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-63/net/unix/Makefile'): No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-63_3.13.0-63.103_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have been reading the many questions on this but was a little scared to just start running random commands as most peoples problems seemed to be resolved quite easily and I have no idea what some of them are doing!.

Here is a little sys info:

```
# uname -r
3.13.0-62-generic
```

-

```
# du -sk *|sort -n
48      lost+found
168     config-3.13.0-59-generic
168     config-3.13.0-61-generic
168     config-3.13.0-62-generic
168     config-3.13.0-63-generic
180     memtest86+.bin
180     memtest86+.elf
180     memtest86+_multiboot.bin
1144    abi-3.13.0-59-generic
1144    abi-3.13.0-61-generic
1144    abi-3.13.0-62-generic
1144    abi-3.13.0-63-generic
3320    System.map-3.13.0-59-generic
3320    System.map-3.13.0-61-generic
3320    System.map-3.13.0-62-generic
3320    System.map-3.13.0-63-generic
5084    grub
5700    vmlinuz-3.13.0-59-generic
5700    vmlinuz-3.13.0-61-generic
5700    vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic
5700    vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic
19840   initrd.img-3.13.0-59-generic
19844   initrd.img-3.13.0-61-generic
19844   initrd.img-3.13.0-62-generic
```

-

```
# df
Filesystem            1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1                4095616 2243320   1852296  55% /
none                          4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                    4072164       4   4072160   1% /dev
tmpfs                    816696    1076    815620   1% /run
none                       5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                    4083476       8   4083468   1% /run/shm
none                     102400       0    102400   0% /run/user
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr    3997376 2231708   1539572  60% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg00-var    3997376 1815572   1955708  49% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-home   3997376    8188   3763092   1% /home
```

-

```
# df -h /boot
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1        4.0G  2.2G  1.8G  55% /
```

Can anyone enlighten me on whats going on here as it seems there is room in /boot. I'm still new to Linux so please go easy :), let me know if you need more information, Thank you!

EDIT:

```
# df -i /usr
Filesystem           Inodes  IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr 262144 259723  2421  100% /usr
```

Comment: It seems that it the message points to the /usr mount point, not /boot. Also, could you add to your question the output of `df -i /usr`?

Comment: Hi @adonis, I have added the output, looks like your right the usage is 100%. I will have a look now to see if I can tell whats taking up the space. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got too many (probably very small) files in your file system. You need to delete files to continue. To find the folders containing most files, you can use something like this:

```
for FOLDER in $(ls -d1 /*/); do printf "$(find ${FOLDER} 2>/dev/null |wc -l)\t${FOLDER}\n"; done |sort -rn |head -n10
for FOLDER in $(ls -d1 /usr/*/); do printf "$(find ${FOLDER} 2>/dev/null |wc -l)\t${FOLDER}\n"; done |sort -rn |head -n10
for FOLDER in $(ls -d1 /usr/src/*/); do printf "$(find ${FOLDER} 2>/dev/null |wc -l)\t${FOLDER}\n"; done |sort -rn |head -n10
...
```

Else you will need to back up your system and create a new filesystem with `mke2fs`, using the `-N` option to control the number of inodes.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for this I found some folder to remove, I couldn't get apt to remove the packages so had to take two out manually (not the best option I know) but it seems to have worked. I have now run apt-get autoremove and am on my way to getting things back on track I think :). Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad it helped. :)